# SO: Why is it possible to down-vote a question after the question has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Three points are mentioned as a tooltip on the down-vote-button:

- The question does not show any research effort
- The question is not clear
- The question is not usefull

The first two are pretty self-explaining. But the last one... Well, what's 'not usefull'? Everyone is asking about a specific problem and so the answers are specific to this question.
It can be only usefull to others if they have the *same problem/question* or they can *abstract the solution and use it to solve their problem*. In both cases they should upvote at least the answer that helped them.

So after a question has an accepted answer the first to reasons to downvote are gone:

- There was at least one person that read the question, understand it and could provide a solution, so the second point is gone.
- The first point is opinion-based, but since there is an answer that solved the problem at least one person thought that the research effort of the question was enough that he/she (tried) to answer the question.

If a question that has an *accepted* answer receives a down-vote, it could be only the last reason. But if a question is 'not usefull' for someone after it has an accepted answer, then it should not be down-voted or down-votable since the question or the context of the question are different and the down-voter should create another question about his/her specific problem, might be with a reference that there is this similar question that did not solved his problem.

So long story short: Why is it possible to down-vote a question that *has* an accepted answer?

Comment: Keep in mind that voting is different on meta. Here, downvotes express disagreement, so don't get offended if you're downvoted here.

Comment: Accepted only means: helped the OP most. That doesn't rule out any of the other voting options,up, down, close or delete for that matter.

Comment: Isn't your question much similar to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242916/restriction-on-down-votes-when-the-question-has-been-stablished-and-has-an-accep?rq=1

Comment: Hoe does an accept invalidate the vote reasons? People vote on questions and answers independantly. A great question can have a bad answer and a bad question can have a great answer. An answer in no way, makes a bad question good.

Comment: Here is an easy example: **the question is off-topic**. Sure, it can be answered and accepted, but is the question useful to the community/site?

Comment: @Unitato This is not about voting on meta, but on SO. And meta is the support platform for all stackexchange platforms, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are. If you have a question about Stack Overflow, then ask on their meta site.

Comment: Similar question already asked on MSO: [Disable downvotes on questions that get answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355968)

Comment: @Elias offtopic is a good point, but then it should be flagged as off-topic. Useful... May be I am wrong, but if I ask a question, the answers should be useful for me. And if I answer a question, the answer should be useful for the one who asked. Isn't that the reason for questions getting closed as offtopic if a discussion rises if the provided solution is good or bad?

Comment: @Tom thanks, my fault. I've read the link you posted... seems a pretty hot discussion...

Comment: Well, the issue is almost always the same: when someone requests to remove downvotes (completely or only on answered/accepted questions) or force everyone to explain downvotes, they almost always mean: don't downvote my posts, because I'm sure they are the best in the world and you're unfair (#). Downvotes exists for a reason and Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) needs moderation to improve the overall quality of the whole page. (#) your reason for this post here might be different, but that's why I wrote "almost always", not "always" :P.

Comment: @Tom You're right... again :) Yes, I am asking since a question that I asked one week ago (solved on the same day) received a downvote today. But it's not about removing the downvote. The downvote is okay, since votes are opinion based and the answer that solved my problem might not solved the problem of the voter. Its more about the reasons SO mentions when you should downvote a question, because i think only the first two are valid and if a question is not useful for someone else he/she should ask their own question. But we're getting offtopic already :D Thanks for all your explanations!

Comment: You could think all 3 reasons are invalid but there are other people who do think they are valid.  It's not possible for a reason for a down vote to be invalid unless people are voting because of whom you are which isn't the case of the question you describe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Accept button being clicked just means that the question asker found the answer useful.

Subsequent users visiting the question may find that the question and/or the answer is not useful, and so downvoting is appropriate.

The voter does not vote just for themselves. They are assessing that the question and/or answer is not likely to be useful to subsequent visitors. A net downvote suggests "don't expect much if you decide to open".

Comment: Thats also a good point. Seems this is opinion based... If the original question is not usefull to another user should he/she down-vote the question since his/her search-key-words shows this question as a possible solution or should he/she create his/her own question without touching the one provided by his/her search.

Comment: The voter does not vote just for themselves. They are assessing that the question and/or answer is not likely to be useful to subsequent visitors. A net downvote suggests "don't expect much if you decide to open".

Comment: Thats a really good explanation that I can accept. Thanks!